# Sass. Check If Custom Ruby Function Exists

Tags: ruby, function, sass, mixins

I've written a Sass (SCSS) CSS3 `@gradient` mixin that also outputs a base64 encoded SVG string for IE9.

This mixin relies upon this custom ruby function be required in the user's Sass "watch" file:

```
require 'sass'
require 'base64'

module Sass::Script::Functions
    def base64Encode(string)
        assert_type string, :String
        Sass::Script::String.new(Base64.encode64(string.value))
    end
    declare :base64Encode, :args => [:string]
end
```

which is called like so: `base64Encode($svgStr)`.

However, I'd like to release my mixin library, and don't want to impose that this custom function be required.

For example, AFAIK [Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) for VS2012 has no way of including custom functions. If it isn't included, then I don't want to output the base64 rule.

So, is it possible to detect in the mixin whether `base64Encode` exists as a custom function? Otherwise, you end up with something like:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,base64Encode('<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" viewBox=\"0 0 1 1\" preserveAspectRatio=\"none\"><linearGradient id=\"g522\" gradientUnits=\"userSpaceOnUse\" x1=\"0%\" y1=\"0%\" x2=\"0%\" y2=\"100%\"><stop stop-color=\"white\" offset=\"0\" /><stop stop-color=\"whitesmoke\" offset=\"1\" /></linearGradient><rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" fill=\"url(#g522)\" /></svg>')");
```

instead of

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRo PSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNl cnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZzUy MiIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIHgxPSIwJSIgeTE9 IjAlIiB4Mj0iMCUiIHkyPSIxMDAlIj48c3RvcCBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSJ3aGl0 ZSIgb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiAvPjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IndoaXRlc21va2Ui IG9mZnNldD0iMSIgLz48L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50PjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9 IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZzUyMikiIC8+ PC9zdmc+ ");
```

Or is possible to somehow search inside the returned string to check whether "base64Encode" is there and to ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pull request (which has been merged) gives you a 'function-exists' function: https://github.com/nex3/sass/pull/821

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't seem to work. I updated to Sass 3.2.12 from 3.2.8, and the following code always produces "true":

if (function-exists(base64Encode)) {
 debug true;
}
else {
 debug false;
}

(@ removed as SO doesn't allow them)

Comment: I'm guessing you need the latest 3.3 release candidate. If that doesn't work, maybe create an issue on GitHub.